# Custom css to rearrange the header positioning in mobile size screen

Tags: css, wordpress

im using wordpress oceanwp theme to create my ecommerce website. Im using medium header sytle for m website. however, i wan my mobile screen to show a different header style of "minimal".

So is used the custom css code to fix this. However, the arrangement in header are (logo/cart icon/menu). But what i expected is rearrange it's position to (menu/Logo/cart icon).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
.top-header-wrap.clr {
width: 50%;
}
.bottom-header-wrap.clr {
width: 50%;
}
div#site-header-inner {
display: flex;
}
.oceanwp-mobile-menu-icon.clr.mobile-right {
height: 100%;
line-height: 100px;
}
}
```

Is there any css code the can help me to solve problem. I expected to get my mobile size screen's header with the arrangement of (Menu/Logo/Cart Icon)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can you Please send the html code how they are now

or

You have to put the code like this

```css
.header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header div{margin:0 10%; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div>menu</div>
<div>logo</div>
<div>Cart</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this for [flexbox ordering](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items). 
Use display flex for `parent class` of header elements and custom order can be specified like this :

`.box :nth-child(1) { order: 2; }`

[image]